# Deleting the last Instantiated GameObject from a List and Scene

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, instantiation

So I'm missing something that's probably pretty straightforward to some, but I'm having trouble with it. I've created a List (msgSymbols) that gets populated with a new GameObject every time a button gets pressed (it's basically a custom keyboard) which then gets instantiated to a Grid Layout.

But how do I then delete only the last GameObject on that list and update the Grid Layout to reflect that change? (like hitting a backspace button on the keyboard)? The delete key code that I currently have is throwing error: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index

How do I resolve this?

```
public string prefabPath;

List<GameObject> msgSymbols = new List<GameObject>();
Vector3 symbolPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
GameObject currentChar;
GameObject msgPanel;
Vector3 symbolScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

GameObject[] charKeys;
GameObject deleteKey;

private int index = 0;

void Start()
{
    msgPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MessagePanel");
    charKeys = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SymbolKey");
    deleteKey = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DeleteKey");
}

#region IPointerClickHandler implementation

public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (transform.CompareTag("SymbolKey"))
    {
        // Load a GameObject into the msgSymbols List
        // and store the last character added in a variable (lastChar)

        msgSymbols.Add((GameObject)Resources.Load(prefabPath));         
        currentChar = msgSymbols.Last<GameObject>();    

        // Instantiate the last character (lastChar) added to msgSymbols List

        GameObject symbol = Instantiate(currentChar, symbolPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        // Define transforms for symbol

        symbol.transform.SetParent(msgPanel.transform);
        symbol.transform.localScale = symbolScale;
    }

    if (transform.CompareTag("DeleteKey"))
    {
        Debug.Log (currentChar);

        GameObject toDestroy = msgSymbols[msgSymbols.Count - 1];
        msgSymbols.RemoveAt(msgSymbols.Count - 1);
        Destroy(toDestroy);

        Debug.Log(msgSymbols.Count);
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your problem is that you have a `GameObject` that isn't going away when you want to get rid of it.  I don't know how the code you aren't showing here works, but it seems possible that you are removing the object from the list, which doesn't have any effect on your scene because the `GameObject` still exists as part of the scene.  Just removing it from the list won't have any effect on it by default.  Try calling `Destroy` on the object after removing it from the list.

```
Debug.Log (lastChar);

GameObject toDestroy = msgSymbols[msgSymbols.Count - 1];
msgSymbols.RemoveAt(msgSymbols.Count - 1);
Destroy(toDestroy);

Debug.Log(msgSymbols.Count);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've updated the code above to reflect your change. I'm getting an error now when I hit the delete key: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index and Debug.Log(msgSymbols.Count) is just returning a 'null' How do I resolve these?

Comment: Are you pressing delete when you have nothing in the list?  You'll have to do some special handling for that.  Otherwise, I'm not sure.  Try debugging your program.  If you aren't able to figure things out from there, I would recommend opening another question with an exact stacktrace and the steps you are taking to get this exception.

Answer (score 1):

The code here isn't calling Destroy() on the object. Removing it from the list doesn't make it go away, since Unity keeps track of all gameObjects independent of anything you do.  `Destroy()` and `Instantiate()` are the ways to remove or add gameObjects from the game.

Comment: Right, missed that. I've updated the code about to add destroy but I'm still getting the an error:  ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it coming from         `msgSymbols.RemoveAt(msgSymbols.Count - 1)`? You might just want rebuild your list in the `lateUpdate()` step, removing any gameObject reference which has become null

Comment: Okay, so I should put msgSymbols.RemoveAt(msgSymbols.Count - 1) in LateUpdate? What should I put in there?