# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to remove/destroy GameObject from List and Scene

Tags: c#, list, indexing, unity-game-engine, range

This is a follow up on a different issue from a topic I posted earlier.

I'm trying to remove a `GameObject` from a List and subsequently destroy it from the scene as well but I'm have trouble doing so. When I click on the delete button on screen I get the error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List'1[UnityEngine.GameObject].get_Item (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)
>
> InstantiateSymbol.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at Assets/_Scripts/InstantiateSymbol.cs:58)
>
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
>
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction'1 functor) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
>
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

How do I fix this?

```
public string prefabPath;

List<GameObject> msgSymbols = new List<GameObject>();
Vector3 symbolPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
GameObject currentChar;
GameObject msgPanel;
Vector3 symbolScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

GameObject[] charKeys;
GameObject deleteKey;

void Start()
{
    msgPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MessagePanel");
    charKeys = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SymbolKey");
    deleteKey = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DeleteKey");
}

#region IPointerClickHandler implementation

public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (transform.CompareTag("SymbolKey"))
    {
        // Load a GameObject into the msgSymbols List
        // and store the last character added in a variable (lastChar)

        msgSymbols.Add((GameObject)Resources.Load(prefabPath));         
        currentChar = msgSymbols.Last<GameObject>();    

        // Instantiate the last character (lastChar) added to msgSymbols List

        GameObject symbol = Instantiate(currentChar, symbolPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        // Define transforms for symbol

        symbol.transform.SetParent(msgPanel.transform);
        symbol.transform.localScale = symbolScale;

        Debug.Log(msgSymbols.Count);
    }

    if (transform.CompareTag("DeleteKey"))
    {
        int totalChar = msgPanel.transform.childCount;
        Debug.Log (totalChar);

        GameObject charToDestroy = msgSymbols[msgSymbols.Count - 1];
        msgSymbols.RemoveAt(msgSymbols.Count - 1);

        Destroy(charToDestroy);

        Debug.Log(msgSymbols.Count);
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Is `msgSymbols` empty?

Comment: I see nothing obvious so if you can include the full error message and the stack trace if you have it so we can see where it is failing. Is it at the RemoveAt or Destroy?

Comment: Nope, I'm doing Debug.Log(msgSymbols.Count); and it's incrementing up as symbols get added to msgPanel.

Comment: Did you tried to debug line by line?

Comment: Is the stack trace the entire length of the error message in the Console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting the last Instantiated GameObject from a List and Scene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412526/deleting-the-last-instantiated-gameobject-from-a-list-and-scene)

Comment: Hi Andrew - one of the commenters from the previous post recommend opening another question with an exact stacktrace and the steps I'm taking to get this exception.

Comment: Try swapping the `Destroy` and the `msgSymbols.RemoveAt` lines.  It may be that the Destroy is looking in the list?  It basically seems to be trying to access a particular position on the list but it doesn't exist at the time it tries to remove

Comment: Oh man, I wish that worked...

Comment: The error includes "Parameter name: index". Is there something I'm missing there? I mean I'm not doing anything with an index, I figured Lists took care of that themselves.

Comment: @greyBow The error is occurring on the line `GameObject charToDestroy = msgSymbols[msgSymbols.Count - 1];`.  When you access an item in a `List<T>` you pass an `index` value.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The only way that the `index` that you are passing can be out of range is if it is less than zero, which means `msgSymbols.Count` is zero.  As Brien asked on your other question are you hitting the delete button before you add any objects to the list?

Comment: I am not hitting the delete button before adding objects.

Comment: Put a breakpoint just before that and run in debug? You'll be able to see the values of everything at that moment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access the element -1 from a list something that its obviously wrong. That happens when `msgSymbols.Count`  is 0, then you are actually doing `msgSymbolx[0-1]` which throws The ArgumentOutOfRange exception.

Based on your description and on the method's name, you are clicking in the "Delete" button when you already removed all the GameObjects from the list.

The .NET compiler (mono's one in case of unity) generates the method called get_Item(Int32 index) for the [] operator, so this

```
msgSymbols[msgSymbols.Count - 1];
```

Translates internally to

```
msgSymbols.get_Item(msgSymbols.Count - 1);
```

which is why that method's name appears in the stack trace.